# Why do I see transparent background behind my image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I used the blur effect on an image

[image]

But when I do that I see a weird transparent background through the effect at the top and bottom of the image. I can see this thing even sometimes when I crop the image. When I try to rotate the image, sometimes the rotated image will have the transparent background behind it which is in the shape of the image when it was not rotated.

[image]

And at this thing appears at the bottom edge too

[image]

Comment: If you apply a hard blur to an entire image it will feather the edges, try selecting the image first, using the selection tools, in it's entirity and then apply the blur.

Comment: what do you mean by a hard blur? I dont quite understand..

Comment: A hard blur meaning a heavy blur, when you take the slider very high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image has a single pixel of transparency in the edge or elsewhere, that transparency spreads when the image is blurred. That is the case easily if a layer is moved.

Comment: oh so when I cropped it, I might've moved it..